# Why does my iPhoto masters file taking up a lot of storage?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos.app, storage

I want to clear some storage from my Mac and it shows that my masters file is 94.7GB, however I only have 2500 pictures and the iPhoto software says it takes up 15.8GB.

Why is the masters folder so large? Does it have every photo I have ever uploaded onto it?

Also how would I go about clearing it? Just by deleting individual pictures?

Comment: You could start by emptying the Trash in iPhoto

Comment: Also check 'Photos' under the Library header - that will keep things you think you have thrown away from other categories & long forgotten about.

Answer (score 1):

The Masters Folder also contains some Pictures you already deleted. So you can empty the Trash (also a Comment to you Question).

This will clean up some storage. I had the problem that iPhoto created some duplicats, because i importet form my old Mac the iPhotoLib. If the Images on have other names but if the Data is the same you can find them with Tools like Gemini.

I hope this will solve your Problems ;)